# Stripe + NextJs - window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, next.js

I'm trying to use Stripe in NextJs https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/blob/master/README.md#server-side-rendering-ssr

I keep getting the error "window is not defined". Am I missing something? The code is at the link above.

Comment: You're not using the above code, because componentDidMount only runs on the client, not on the server

Comment: Have you check out the official example by Zeit , here I link it to you , https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-stripe-typescript .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`"window is not defined"`** is shown due to the fact that your code is `server-side` rendered and can't access the global **window** object because that is something only a client will understand. move your code inside `lifecycle methods` as they run only on the `client-side`.

Comment: what are the lifecycle methods?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a dynamic import for the Stripe component and disable SSR.

StripeForm component file (export as default) 
`component/StripeForm.tsx`

Import it dynamically in `pages/stripe` like so

`const StripeForm = dynamic(() => import("../components/StripeForm"), { ssr: false } )`

```
return (
   ...
   <StripeForm />
   ...
)
```